# Method not found: 'Int32 Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueueMessage.get_MaxNumberOfMessagesToPeek()'

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, azure-queues

Anyone got this error in Visual Studio 2012, while trying to peek the Azure Queue Storage ?
Just started happening to me today...

Comment: What version of storage client library are you using?

Comment: I am using Azure SDK 2.6

Comment: The issue has went away as fast as it arrived, an odd error message to receive however!

Comment: Any chance of conflicting nugets?